# How can I add a horizontal line over the x axis in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to add  a red line over the x axis of a plot in R.

I have:

```
    plot(model$res, model$fit, xlab = expression(hat(y)), 
         ylab = 'Residusals', 
         main = 'Residuals vs. Predicted',
         pch = 4, col = 'red')
    abline(h = 0, col = 'red')
```

However, the line is not drawn over the x axis. I'd prefer not to delete or change the color of the axis if possible.

Comment: `par("usr")` will return the maximum and minimums of your plotting region for checking purposes.

Comment: Of course right after posting I realized I was making a dumb mistake. I switched placing the residuals and the predicted values on the axes. 0 should be at the center of the y axis, not the bottom. Thanks anyways.